# Has $x^3 - x +1$ a root in $\mathbb{Q}(a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field

> Decide if $x^3 - x +1$ has a root in $\mathbb{Q}(a)$, with $a \in\mathbb{C}$ such that $a^3 + a + 1 = 0$.

Comment: If $a $ is a root then $a^3-a+1=0$ giving $a^3+1=0$ and $a=0$

Comment: Root should be of the form $\alpha +\beta a$ where $\alpha, \beta $ are rational numbers. No?

Comment: @JohnWatson You forgot ${}+\gamma a^2$.

Comment: Yes, thanks.....

Comment: The elements of the field $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is of form $\alpha+\beta a$. Or I am missing something. Where $\gamma$ comes from?

Comment: $x^3 + x + 1$ is the minimal of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\{1, a, a^2\}$ is a basis.

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan You're missing that the polynomial of $a$ has degree three, not degree two.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschirnhaus_transformation

Comment: OK. Thanks so we are extending the $\mathbb{Q}$ with all roots of that polynomial? Or I am missing something again?

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan No, I think it's $\Bbb Q$ with one arbitrary root of that polynomial. I don't know whether that implies all roots, but it's not automatically so.

Comment: I am trying to understand $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ this means $\alpha + \beta \sqrt 2$ what is the difference for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3 )$? Sorry I know this may be obvious.

Comment: $\sqrt{3}$ is no different. But the point is that you need the quotient ring to be a ring! In your case there is no way to write $a^2$ in terms of $a$ and $1$. Note that you _can_ write $a^3$ in terms of lower powers -- $a^3=-a-1$. And now $a^4 = -a^2-a, a^5=-a^3-a^2 = -(-a-1)-a^2$, etc.

Comment: Nothing is different for $\sqrt 3$. For $\sqrt[3]{2}$, however, the resulting field, as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$, has dimension $3$.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that we get a negative conclusion from the observation that the discriminants of the two polynomials are coprime (together with the fact that there are no discriminant $=1$ extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$). But, it's past my bedtime, and I can't think straight enough. Anyway, something simpler may be out there.

Comment: Thank you. It is clear now.

Comment: Are you familiar with some tools provided by algebraic number theory? In addition to using the discriminant we see that the prime $p=3$ is totally inert in one extension, but splits in the other. Therefore the cubic extensions are not the same. Ergo, they intersect trivially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the idea given by Jyrki Lahtonen, I think the following is relatively elementary.

Let $K$ be the splitting field of $x^3+x+1=0$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then the Galois group $G(K/\mathbb{Q})$ cannot fix the root of $x^3-x+1=0$ and therefore both cubics split in $K$.

However, this would mean that $K$ contained $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-31},\sqrt{-23})$ and we would have $4=[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ as a factor of $6=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$.

Answer (score -1):

We can write an arbitrary element of $\Bbb Q(a)$ as $x=\alpha+\beta a+\gamma a^2$, with $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\Bbb Q$. Let's plug that element into our equation: $$x^3-x+1=(\alpha+\beta a+\gamma a^2)^3 - (\alpha+\beta a+\gamma a^2) + 1.$$

You can expand this, reducing powers of $a$ by using the formula $a^3=-a-1$. Finally, you obtain something of the form $A+Ba+Ca^2$, where, $A$, $B$ and $C$ are expressions in $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$. Set all three to zero. If there is a rational solution, then you've shown that $x\in\Bbb Q(a)$

Comment: Yes, but I would like to use more theory...

Comment: _Usually_, this approach is long and not really helpful (for instance, some times it comes down to solving the exact same equation only in a new variable). If there is a reason it is easier this time, I would love to hear more about it.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs:  you are of course correct but finding a rational solution to $A, B, C = 0$ doesn't look much easier than the original question to me!

Comment: In that case, you probably want to look at a Tschirhaus transformation. I remember seeing a calculation of this sort in Delone & Fadeev's book on cubics, but it's a been a while, and I don't remember the details.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34522/cubic-polynomials-that-generate-the-same-extension